# How can i download Excel file from physical path using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

Hi I want to download the excel file by clicking the button.

let me explain my scenario,

first I have created by excel file at run time.  for me the file is created in  my proj folder.

but I don't know how to download the file in physical path.

> html

```
<button ng-click="exportData()" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-create">Export</button>
```

> controller.js

```
$scope.exportData = function () {
data='hi';    
SKUdataName ='how';    
UOMdataName ='are';  
cartdatatype='you';
     $http.get('/Getexcel/' + data + '/' + SKUdataName + '/' + UOMdataName + '/' + cartdatatype).then(function (response) {


               //here what should i write to download the file from physical path              

                         });
};
```

[image]
can any one tell me how to download the  file  from physical path.
thanks,

Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

you can open the excel file url in new  tab like this:

```
.controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.exportData = function(){
            data='hi';    
            SKUdataName ='how';    
            UOMdataName ='are';  
            cartdatatype='you';
            var url = '/Getexcel/' + data + '/' + SKUdataName + '/' + UOMdataName + '/' + cartdatatype;
            $window.open(url, '_blank');
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: after i add this code file is not downloading see the new tab pic @gaurav srivastava

Comment: there should be something wrong with your url or file generation, because its browser's default behavior to download the file if file path is right.

Comment: that is not file path, i want to know how to set the physical path "../Excel.xlsx". this is my path url

Comment: do you have access to physical path inside controller scope?

Comment: I think yes only

Comment: then replace url with that path

Comment: if i gave url then also file is not downloading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146608/discussion-between-gaurav-srivastava-and-vinoth).